# How do I control access to a downloadable file based on session id with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a testing system that records the answers a user puts in and then grades the test. When it's done, it creates an easily readable table of the answers and the score the user achieved. I want to record that file and put it in a log file.

So I setup a file with the user's username, and record all of the test results in that file. Problem is, those files are open to the public. I have a login system that checks the session ID and allows or doesn't allow access, but I can't get the code into those newly generated files.

So how should I go about doing this? I've used the `.htaccess` file to block access to the folder, but I was hoping for a more fluid solution.

Is it possible to dynamically write PHP code to a newly created file, using PHP? (so it auto-generates the login check into each of its auto-generated log files)

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: dynamically writing PHP code using your PHP program sounds like something that would be likely to be insecure unless you're very very careful with it. Even if you're not running it using `eval()`, the same issues of dynamically generated code would apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before creation of the tables file you can also do a simple append to that file where you'll insert the tables code the PHP sesssion check code. You can do this using PHP [**file writing functions**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

Since the PHP session checking code will be constant, this approach is far much easier.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

so what I did was add my 'include(authorizeAdmin.php)' code into a template file. Then when a new user is made, it just copies that file as their username. When they take a test, we append the test data to the end of the log file.

I thought that php would erase any php code when appending, but i was wrong. It worked great. Thanks William!

Answer (score 1):

Save the file outside the web root. Anything outside of `public_html` (or whatever your web root is) is completely inaccessible from the web, but can be accessed by a PHP file if it sees you are logged in, for example.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea to me, but its saying: 
'Warning: fopen(/logs/realm/tuser.html) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory'
Even though the file does exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to dynamically write PHP code to a newly created file,
>   using PHP? (so it auto-generates the login check into each of its
>   auto-generated log files)

Yes it is. You can create a template file that just has the login checks, file_get_contents on that and then write that to the top of your files. Then, use [__halt_compiler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php) to stop PHP from interpreting the rest of the file. Then you can start reading from `__COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__` and echo THAT to the client.

If you want a simpler solution than using `__halt_compiler()` you can simply create a php file that will echo the results to the user after a session check.

Better yet, you can insert all of the results into a database. Then you just need to have one page that checks the username, fetches the results, and then outputs it all to the user.

Comment: If I was to insert all these results to a MySQL database, what would be the best data type to do that in? I mean, it'll be several hundred lines of code that would go into SQL. Is that really an efficient way of storing the data? (I'm not great with SQL)

Answer (score 0):

a) store the files somewhere OUTSIDE of your site's document root, so they're not directly reachable via URL.

b) have a single PHP script be the gateway to accessing those files. The code would be vaugely like

```
<?php

$fileID = $_GET['id'];

if (user_is_allowed_access($fileID)) {
    send_file_to_user($fileID);
} else {
    die("go away");
}
```

once you've settled the access/permissions checking stuff, the actual sending of the file can quite literally be as simple as `readfile('/path/to/file/on/server')`